# Add matching html tag

Tags: vimrc, filetype-html

In Textmate I can do something like when I have the following:

```
<div>
    <p>new
```

If I press <kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> it will add in the matching tag. So when I press it once, it will look like:

```
<div>
    <p>new</p>
```

If I press it a second time:

```
<div>
    <p>new</p></div>
```

And if I press it a third time, nothing will happen as there are no open tags. What is the best way to do this in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vim, you can complete open html tags and close tags using *omni-completion*, invoked via <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>ctrl-o</kbd>. To do this though, you must first type `<` or `</` depending on which tag you want.  For close, the tag corresponding to the nearest unclosed open tag will be chosen, for example:

```
<div>
  <p>asdf</p>
</[]    <-- PRESS ctrl-x ctrl-o HERE
```

This is a little bit inconvenient, so we can make a mapping for close tag:

```
inoremap <c-b> </<c-x><c-o>
```

Pressing <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> in insert mode will enter the desired close tag.
This map works, but isn't ideal because it will enter `</>` when no close tab is appropriate.  We can modify the map to help

```
inoremap <c-b> <c-\><c-o>a</<c-x><c-o><c-r>=get(v:completed_item, 'word', '>') ==# '>' ? "\<lt>c-u>" : ''<cr>
```

The idea behind this map is if only `>` was inserted, backspace the inserted text.  The point of `<c-\><c-o>a` is to limit the amount backspaced over with `<c-u>`.

Comment: I did not know about <c-\>, I feel like a whole new world has just opened before me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the plugin called [vim-closetag](https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag) which does exactly this.

The big advantage over the default omni-completion is you don't need to type as much.

The matching closing tag will be automatically inserted after your cursor. Just type `>` by default to insert a new line between those new tags, pretty convenient.